# JavaScript Sliding Sidebar Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create this sidebar menu to the right using HTML CSS transitions and standard JavaScript and I also imported some FontAwesome icons.

My code looks like this (the JavaScript code is inside the HTML document):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sidebar Menu</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b1956a1c85.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li> 
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a></li> 
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-cogs"></i></a></li> 
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-wrench"></i></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-tools"></i></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>

<a href="#" class="button"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>

<script> 

    let btn = document.querySelector('.button'), 
    side = document.querySelector('.sidebar');

    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if(btn.innerHTML === '<i class="fas fa-bars"></i>') {
            btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>';
            side.style.marginLeft = '0px';
        } else if (btn.innerHTML === '<i class = "fas fa-times"></i>') {
            btn.innerHTML = '<i class= "fas fa-bars"></i>';
            side.style.marginLeft = '-25px';
        }
    });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And my CSS page looks like this:

```
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #af8f36;
}

.sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #6e36af;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: -125px;
    transition: 0.5s;

}

.sidebar ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 100px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.sidebar ul li a:hover {
    background: #5d2e94;
}

.button {
    float: left;
    padding: 27px 20px;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}
```

For some reason the sidebar won't slide to the right when I click on the hamburger button. Can someone explain to me why? Is my JavaScript code correct?

Comment: i think some code is missing , can you check it

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp - try this

Comment: check in the console panel its shows u what happens when u click

Answer (score 0):

I found your problem:
In your JS code you check if the inner HTML of the Button is:

```
<i class="fas fa-bars"></I>
```

But Fontawesome adds a new Attribute to your `<I>` Element. So now it's inner HTML is:

```
<i class="fas fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></I>
```

I would recommend using a variable in js or something similar to check/save wether your menu is open or not. 
Your way could easy lead to more bugs.

In Addition, for better performance I would recommend animating with Transform not margin, if possible.